# setTransacted method in the JpaPagingItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

What is the purpose of method setTransacted in the JpaPagingItemReader? What will exactly happens when we set it as true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html#setTransacted-boolean-), this flag means the read operation will be wrapped in a transaction (which defaults to `true`).

Typically, you don't want items to be changed while you are reading them (batch processing is about fixed, immutable data sets). If this flag is set to `false`, then undesired changes to the entities might be reflected in the items returned by the reader, which could be problematic. So the purpose of this flag is to guarantee the consistency of items returned by the reader.

Comment: What does it mean by read operation being wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: This means: 1) start transaction 2) read a page of items 3) commit transaction. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L193 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L222.